# How to output biggest array elements if they repeats and need to be output all

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array. I need to find biggest element of it. If element repeats in array once again, I need to output and it. What is the program to output all biggest elements, if they repeats?

I tried to create new array, but somehow it did not work.

For example

```
int[] array = { 15, 2, 16, 16, 7, 3, 16};
```

And expected output

```
16 16 16

int[] array = { 1, 2, 1, 16, 7, 3, 15 };
```

expected output

```
 16
```

Comment: Any code? Inputs, Expected Outputs, Code Attempts?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The more detail you provide the more likely you are to get an answer. Please see the following link n how to ask qood questions here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you want the largest element that repeats, or only the largest element *if* it repeats? Some sample input and expected output would be very helpful. If you have `{1, 2, 3, 2, 1}`, it's not clear to me if you want to print nothing (since `3` is the largest but it doesn't repeat) or `2` (since it's the largest of the elements that repeat).

Answer (score 1):

A more "old fashioned" approach would be to walk through the array and keep track of the largest item (and the number of times you encounter it) as you go:

```
var items = new[] {15, 2, 16, 16, 7, 3, 16};
var largest = int.MinValue;
var count = 0;

// Walk through each item in the array, and compare it to the largest one found
// If it equals the largest, then increment our count. If it's greater than
// the largest, then set largest equal to this item and set count equal to 1.
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (item == largest)
    {
        count++;
    }
    else if (item > largest)
    {
        largest = item;
        count = 1;
    }
}

// Output the largest item 'count' times
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    Console.Write(largest + " ");
}
```